# Rails, Stripe, when to POST to Charges controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout in my application. I want to make it so that when guest users want to purchase an item, they are asked to create an account. Once the account is created they are charged and a receipt is created for them.

For non-guest users, my Stripe payment runs exactly the way I want it. What I would like to do is once I have created the user in my User controller's create action, have it essentially POST to my charges controller's create action so that the charge is then made automatically when they create their account.

But reading around it seems that posting between controllers is a very non rails thing to do. So I'm not sure how I should do this such that it cooperates with the MVC pattern. In my mind the guest user has already clicked to buy the ticket so it only makes sense they shouldn't have to click again to do it.

I can't see a neat way to do this without copying a load of code from my charges controller's create action into my user controller's create action - but that seems absurd. Is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the charge action into its own model such as `Payment` or `Charge`, which would allow you to call the action by passing the necessary parameters. For example

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.charge(amount, token)
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
            :amount => amount * 100,      # Amount is based in cents
            :source => token,    # Could be existing credit card token or JS Stripe token
            :currency => "usd",
            :description => "Test Charge"
        })
    end
end
```

So then from any controller you can call it as such:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        user = User.new(user_params)

        if user.save
            add_to_flash = ""

            # You could do another conditional here to check if the card should be processed
            if params[:card_should_charged]
                Payment.charge("1200", "tok_8asdfa9823r23")  #=> $12.00 and the charge token
                add_to_flash = " and your payment was accepted"
            end

            flash[:notice] = "Your account was created" + add_to_flash + "."
            redirect_to whatever_path
        else
            flash[:error] = "Failed to create user."
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

You would obviously have to create the conditional yourself, most likely in the view and pass that in when the user creation form is submitted.

If you need to generate the `Payment` model without a table (incase you just want to use the model to process payments, not to store them), then you could use:

```
rails g model Payment --no-migration
```

to generate it.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much. It's a good general method to know.

Comment: Can I ask a quick related question to put my mind at rest? Currently I'm passing a load of parameters to a signup form view - the URL looks like "http://localhost:3000/signup?amount=75306&email=email%40email.com&stripeToken=tok_17CD5iF5yf5JD010v47usr7G&ticket_purchase=true" - is this a good way to keep these parameters? There shouldn't be any problem with security right, because as long as my stripe private key is still private it wouldn't matter if someone got hold of the stripe token?